# jQuery Countdown plugin issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm trying to use [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) to count down to a particular date in 'full' mode (that is, the `compact` option set to `false`). The problem is, the last date component, whether it is seconds, minutes, or whatever has been specified in the *format* option breaks off on to the next line in Internet Explorer (checked on both IE7 and IE8) when the timer is rendered:

```
    $(function () {
        var austDay = new Date(2009, 11, 11);
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay, 
                                          format: 'ODHMS', 
                                          compact: false});
    });
```

Unfortunately I can't provide a screen grab at this time as I'm using a mac. It works just fine in compact mode, but it's not nearly as pretty.

Has anyone experienced this and devised a workaround/fix? Any ideas?

Comment: Amazing, I'm using the latest version, two years after you've asked this, and this issue still happens. Annoying. Thank you for asking this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try adding a style rule in?  This will eliminate line breaks inside the container.

```
#defaultCountdown { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Or...am I completely misunderstanding your problem?